# Branching rule restriction to $\mathrm{O}_9 \Bbb C$ from $\mathrm{GL}_9 \Bbb C$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, branching-rules

On page 427 of Fulton and Harris's *Representation Theory*, the authors give the branching rule for the above restriction as 
$$
\mathrm{Res}_{\mathrm O_m \Bbb C}^{\mathrm{GL}_m \Bbb C} (\Gamma_\lambda) = \bigoplus N_{\lambda \overline \lambda} \Gamma_{\overline \lambda}
$$
where $\lambda$ partitions $m$, $\overline \lambda$ denotes the conjugate partition, $\Gamma_\lambda$ is the irrep of $\mathrm{GL}_m$ with highest weight $\lambda$, and 
$$
N_{\lambda \overline \lambda} = \sum_\delta N_{\delta \overline \lambda \lambda}
$$
is the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient and the sum over all $\delta = (\delta_1 \geq \delta_2 \geq \cdots)$ with all $\delta_i$ even.

**Question**

What if we take $\lambda = (n)$? Then $\Gamma_{(n)} = \mathrm{Sym}^n \Bbb C$ (I believe), and $\overline \lambda = (1, \dots , 1)$. But I am having trouble seeing what $\delta$ will be, or how I will compute this restriction to $\mathrm O_9\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $\bar \lambda$ is **not** the conjugate partition (which is denoted by $\lambda'$ in [FH]) but any partition.

As for your example, if I am not mistaken, $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\mathbb C)$ then restricts to
$$\bigoplus_{k\le n, n-k\text{ even}} \Gamma_{(k)}$$
because $\bar \lambda \le \lambda$ and $N_{(n-k),(k),(n)}=1$.